# Upgrading .Net5 Mvc To .Net7 Mvc Caused Content Security Policy Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, visual-studio-2022, content-security-policy, .net-7.0

I am trying to learn .net mvc. My instructor used .net5 on the course, but I want to build it with .Net 7. I did the necessary things (startup.cs=>program.cs conversions).

So there are 2 .Net7.0 web applications, I can launch them. But when I click redirection button I get following error in the Browsers console:

> aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:234 Refused to connect to
> 'wss://localhost:44375/AuthServer/' because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that
> 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
> fallback.

Same project works on .net 5. And its a very simple mvc, no frontend code but a phrase.

How can I find a solution? Has anyone encountered same problem ? Is this a feature of .Net7?

If there is anything missing in my question please comment , not downgrade, I will fix.

Edit: Solutions I have tried and did not work.:

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' ws: wss:");
    await next();
});
```

- 

And things like that doesn't work on my situation.

- At Microsof Forum they said downgrade your VisualStudio to 17.0.4, but Versions Lower than 17.4 does not support .net 7

Nothing on Stackoverflow was helpful yet

Comment: _"Has anyone encountered same problem"_ Yes! Try searching [so] with "CSP wss"

Comment: Scott Hanselmann even has [a blog post specifically about this issue](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/net-6-hot-reload-and-refused-to-connect-to-ws-because-it-violates-the-content-security-policy-directive-because-web-sockets)